# Advise needed on Table Generation from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-tables

I am creating a new website and have been working with ASP.NET using VB.

My website is for Car Racers (speedway). Id like to provide a list of drivers for the fans in the format like this
http://www.nba.com/lakers/roster?cid=nav_team_expanded

I have all the info in a dataset from my SQL Server Database, but im having all sorts of problems trying to create a table similar to the above.

I'd like it all to be dynamic so no-one needs to edit the website.

What is the best and easiest way to go about this? I have tried various tutorials I have found but none have been able to work effectively.

Many thanks in advance!

This is my code so far. The Dataset is populated with the correct information, its just trying to work out how to create the tables dynamically in a way that displays all drivers.

```
        Dim dsDrivers As DataSet = MSSQL.CustomSQL("WASDA_Drivers", "SELECT CarNo,Name FROM WASDA_Drivers")
    Dim RowsCount As Integer = dsDrivers.Tables(0).Rows.Count / 4

    'Sorts Car Numbers Properly
    Dim CarNos As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    Dim g As Integer
    For z As Integer = 0 To dsDrivers.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If Integer.TryParse(dsDrivers.Tables(0).Rows(z).Item("CarNo"), g) Then
            CarNos.Add(g)
        End If
    Next
    CarNos.Sort()

    Dim rows, cells, j, i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    rows = RowsCount * 2
    cells = 4
    For j = 0 To RowsCount - 1
        Dim oRow As New TableRow()
        For Each z As Integer In CarNos
            For i = 0 To cells - 1
                For x As Integer = 0 To dsDrivers.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    If CarNos(z).ToString = dsDrivers.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item("CarNo") Then
                        Dim oCell As New TableCell
                        oCell.Text = CarNos(z) & " : " & dsDrivers.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item("Name")
                        oRow.Cells.Add(oCell)
                        GoTo NextItem
                    End If
                Next
NextItem:
                    tblDrivers.Rows.Add(oRow)
                Next
                For i = 0 To cells - 1
                    Dim oCell As New TableCell()
                    'oCell.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("row " & j & ", cell " & i))
                    'oCell.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(dsDrivers.Tables(0).Rows(count).Item(0)))
                    oCell.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(CarNos(count) & " : " & dsDrivers.Tables(0).Rows(count).Item(0)))
                    oRow.Cells.Add(oCell)
                    count = count + 1
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Can you at least show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thought i did... woops! Have updated my original post.

Comment: You probably want to look at the built-in web controls like Repeater or DataList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem with displaying a list of products in a catalog. If you want to let the number of drivers per row re-size dynamically to fit the user's screen, the simplest thing to do is to use css to create a class for a fixed-size "tile". Declare the tiles as display=inline-block. I.e. create a box with a fixed width and height. Then use a Repeater that reads from your datasource and creates one instance of this tile for each driver. Don't do anything to force line breaks, except after the very last one -- either but a BR or wrap them in a DIV. Then just let the browser lay them out. It should string them out across the page until it runs out of room, then go to the next row, just like it wraps text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write all this code manually, Instead what you can do is use asp:ListView and set LayoutTemplate and ItemTemplate the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have played around a bit with the repeater and it looks to be exactly what im after!

Having a few dramas getting it going programatically (mainly because my Database Column for Driver Numbers is a VarChar so its sorting 1, 10, 11, 2, 21, 3 etc - but will look at modifying the database).

Many thanks guys, was really stuck with this one!